# how can i use shell to judge the software was installed?

Tags: shell, ubuntu

My pc's os is ubuntu 14.04, I want  write a  script  to auto install some software, I  need  to judge it was not installed before,  for exeample ,I want 
judge  google-chrome  was installed or not,code like this:

```
if [ !which google-chrome  #I knoe this  way was wrong]
do
     download it 
     sudo dpkg  -i  google-chrome*.deb
done 
fi
```

I know  the judge code  if[] is wrong, can you tell me  how  can  I judge  it was not installed use shell ?

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea. I would use `aptitude search`  then `aptitude install`

Comment: can you show your way for exeample judge  google-chrome use shell @Basile Starynkevitch

Comment: You should motivate a lot more your question and give some more specific context (**why** do you want to do this is important, so **edit your question** to improve it). My answer gave some clues.

Comment: you probably mean "to test" or "to check" not "to judge"

Answer (score 2):

Notice that `which` is searching the [`PATH` variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29). See [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/10525/50557). A given user might have directories (such as `$HOME/bin/` or `/usr/local/bin/`  ...) mentioned in his `$PATH` which are not and should not be managed by the packaging system.

Don't forget that Linux is at heart a [multi-user](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-user) system. For example, my wife and my son can use the same PC. Different users are likely to have different `$PATH` settings so would use different set of programs (e.g. thru [execvp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/execvp.3.html) or equivalent called from their shell...).

I don't think you should install, at a system-wide level, the `google-chrome-stable`  package, if the user has some own `google-chrome` program (e.g. in his `$HOME/bin/`, installed thru some other procedure)  But you (and probably even your user) should decide what you'll do in that case.

I would instead test if the `google-chrome-stable` *package* has been installed (but then, you are doing something different that what you are asking).

Perhaps you might test

```
if dpkg -l google-chrome-stable >& /dev/null ; then
  echo google-chrome-stable is installed
fi
```

BTW, I don't think that auto-installing any package without explicit and prior consent of the user is a good idea. You should instead suggest him to install (and that is a very different question, probably a matter of wise auto-completion in the shell).

On my Debian system, `/usr/bin/google-chrome` is a symlink to `/etc/altneratives/google-chrome` which is a symlink to `/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable` which is a symlink to `/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome`. So, with [realpath(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/realpath.1.html), I could also have used

```
if  dpkg -S $(realpath $(which google-chrome)) >& /dev/null ; then
  echo some package gives google-chrome
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use dpkg to check the status of a package name and it will tell you if it's not installed or if it's not active, etc...

Comment: can you  show me a  example code  how to judge  it use  if []  for example  google-chrome?